# Multiple tooltip is not visible when adding dynamic points in chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a chartjs multiple tooltip to display the X & Y axis values in tooltip. But when the data points are added dynamically the tooltip is not visible.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="//www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="updating-chart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

[JS bin link](http://jsbin.com/zibeniboya/1/edit)